# how to accumulate the value according to the key in a defaultdict

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator, key, defaultdict

If I have a defaultdict(list)

```
from collections import defaultdict

d =defaultdict(list)
such as 1: 0
        1:0.2
        1: 0.3
        2: 0.2
        2: 0.4
        2: 0.1
```

...... how I transform it into a similar defaultdict(list)
which values is the accumulation of values of the 1st dict with the same key, but never bigger than 1

```
        1: 0
        1: 0.2
        1: 0.5
        2: 0.2
        2: 0.6
        2: 0.7 
         .....
```

I have only following code so far, it is not quite right :-(

```
 d2 = defaultdict(list)
 for k in d.iterkeys()
          v +=d(k)
          d2[k]. append(v)
```

Comment: Defaultdict allows for ambigious keys? If you call `d [1]`, what does it yield? 0, 0.2 or 0.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original post is a little confusing: the examples look like a multimap rather than a dict of lists.

I assume that you have a defaultdict with lists of numbers and you'd like to create a new defaultdict that contains the cumulative sum of the values in each list.  Try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d2 = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    sum = 0.0
    v2 = []
    for x in v:
        sum += x
        v2.append(sum)
    d2[k] = v2
```

Note that the new defaultdict won't auto-compute cumulative sums as you add new values.

If you have a library like numpy installed, you can use `numpy.cumsum` instead of using a python loop to compute the cumulative sum.

It's not clear to me what exactly you mean by "never bigger than 1."  Do you want to ignore elements after the cumulative sum reaches 1?  Do you want to ignore individual values greater than 1, but keep accumulating smaller ones, even if the sum grows beyond 1?  Do you want to have the same number of elements in each output list, but cap the element values at 1?

Comment: In my data sets the accumulation values should not bigger than 1, it would be a 2nd examination for my previous data generation process..but not quite related to this particular questions.  numpy.cumsum might be a great idea :-)

Answer (score 1):

For reference you can do this more elegantly:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d2 = defaultdict(float)
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    d2[k] += v
```

Comment: Good catch. I saw this in a legacy project and wondered whether this works, but it does. Works only when you use defaultdict with an initialised numeric data type. You can also use use `from collections import Counter`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52035025/11154841.