# Cumulatively add values to python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Suppose ,I have a dictionary

```
key={'a':5}
```

Now ,I want to add values to it cumulatively without overwriting the current value but adding on to it.How to do it?
I am giving an instance:

```
for post in doc['post']:
    if 'wow' in post:
        value=2
        for reactor in post['wow']['reactors']:
            dict_of_reactor_ids.update({reactor['img_id']:value})
    if  'sad' in post:
        value=2
        for reactor in post['sad']['reactors']:
            dict_of_reactor_ids.update({reactor['img_id']:value})
```

Suppose if the dictionary is like this in first iteration

```
dict_of_reactor_ids={101:2,102:1}
```

and NOW I want to increase the value of 101 key by 3 ,then how to do that.

```
dict_of_reactor_ids={101:5,102:1}
```

Now in second iteration of post ,I want to add values to the current values in dictionary without overwriting the current value.
I have tried update method but I think it just updates the whole value instead of adding onto it.

Comment: What do you mean by "add values cumulatively"? Please add examples of the values you want to add and what you want the dictionary to look like afterwards, otherwise it's impossible to tell what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Edited it,Please check again

Comment: You can try collections counter lib

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to accumulate the value according to the key in a defaultdict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947341/how-to-accumulate-the-value-according-to-the-key-in-a-defaultdict)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a typical case of [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter()
>>> c["a"] += 1 # works even though "a" is not yet present
>>> c.update({"a": 2, "b": 2}) # possible to do multiple updates
{"a": 3, "b": 2}
```

In your case the benefit is that it works even when the key is not already in there (default value is 0), and it allows updates of multiple values at once, whereas update on a normal `dict` would overwrite the value as you've noticed.

Comment: I love you man,Thanks.I have one more doubt more , can't we add value to c like in normal dictionary `c={'a':4}

Comment: `c = Counter({"a": 4})` should do it, or `c["a"] = 4`

Comment: ,I encountered the following error [Cumulatively add values to python dictionary without using counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52184270/cumulatively-add-values-to-python-dictionary-without-using-counter),seems like counter is not particular useful in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can also use defaultdict, it "defaults" when there is not yet an existing key-value pair and you still use the cumulative add `+=`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict_of_reactor_ids = defaultdict(int)
dict_of_reactor_ids[101] += 2
dict_of_reactor_ids[102] += 1
dict_of_reactor_ids['101'] += 3
print(dict_of_reactor_ids['101'])
5
```