# Cumulatively add values to python dictionary without using Counter

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, counter

I have a following mongoDBschema-
ObjectIDs are multiple entries in the database ,in which the further data is stored.

```
ObjectId("a")
    posts
        [0]
            comments
                [0]
                    comment
                    fb_id
        [1]
        [2]
        [3]
        [4]

ObjectId("b")
ObjectId("c")
```

I am trying to cumulatively add the sentiment value,I am assigning to the dictionary for each comment corresponding to every fb_id.I tried using counter method but it's values are emptying before entering another id's comment automatically.
Earlier,I asked this question-[Cumulatively add values to python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52029520/cumulatively-add-values-to-python-dictionary) and the output ,I received is below-

```
 Counter({'100002204201460': 0.0})
 Counter({'100002204201460': 0.0, '100025548426588': -0.592})
 Counter({'1490834948': 0.5792,
     '100002204201460': 0.0,
     '100025548426588': -0.592})
```

Counter is emptying itself before entering into another comment of same post.

My implementation-

```
 for doc in result:
     dict_of_comments = Counter()
     for post in doc['posts']: # traverse each user's post
        if 'comments' in post:
        for com in post['comments']:
            s=com['comment']
            vs=analyzer.polarity_scores(s) //sentiment analyser
            dict_of_comments[com['fb_id']] += vs['compound']
            pprint.pprint(dict_of_comments)
```

How to do it correctly,I just want to cumulatively add values without losing any of the values as currently ,I am loosing using Counter.

**Input in one of the objectID**

```
 {
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b7fa2a745d12b10324d3a01"),
  "date_time" : "24, Aug 2018 11:44",
  "original_query" : "sanjeevnewar",
  "posts" : [ 
           "comments" : [ 
            {
                "comment" : "आशीष जी को कोटि कोटि प्रणाम।",
                "commentator" : "Amrit Kumar Deb",
                "fb_id" : "100002204201460"
            }, 
            {
                "comment" : "Double standard is not going to work  Stop ogling over Muslim women",
                "commentator" : "Akif Khan",
                "fb_id" : "100025548426588"
            }
          ]
         ]
       }
```

**Output** ,if a standard dictionary is used without using Counter is as below

```
 {'100002204201460': 0.0}
 {'100002204201460': 0.0, '100025548426588': -0.296}
```

This is just a sample output, not all values are included.
But the issue is if my program encounters a same fb_id value(which is `100002204201460`) in later posts, then it will just rewrite the dictionary with new values rather than adding values to it.
How to do it?

Comment: Now, as I have edited, do you think it is complete?

Comment: If you think the question is still incomplete then please do let me know.

Comment: I don't think your question is complete yet, no. What is the 'object id'? How does the expected output correspond with the input? It's not clear to me how your expected output consists of two separate dictionaries, for example. Would a dictionary mapping object id to a `Counter()` do here?

Comment: Now,Is it complete? and I didn't get your last question

Comment: Perhaps you can show more information about the results, and show how object ids are related to the output? Sample input and expected output are much clearer when explicitly included.

Comment: Could you please check again?I avoided adding all this information ,because in today's world of instant gratification nobody reads this long a question.

Comment: So how does moving `dict_of_comments = Counter()` *outside* of the `for doc in result` loop produce incorrect outputs? You state that you want to add up the compound sentiment values per fb_id, but the missing link is how your expected output should be separate dictionaries. When should a separate counter be produced?

Comment: Each ObjectId represents a single user, if I am having a single counter outside the `for doc in result` loop ,won't I'll get a single dictionary at the end of the program.In this case as I am emptying the standard dictionary after `for doc in result` so every time ,I am encountering a new objectID(a new user) ,I am getting a new dictionary.Correct me ,if I am wrong in my thought process.

Comment: Provided `for doc in result:` only produces every objectID just once, sure. But you are asking how to *cumulatively add values*, which would mean you wanted to add up the `fb_id` values together *across* objectIds. Perhaps you are asking how you can keep all separate counters? Then add them in a list, or create a dictionary mapping object id to counter.